# Disabling SSLv3 but still supporting SSLv2Hello in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, java, poodle

Many SSL clients, notably JDK 6, use the SSLv2Hello protocol to handshake with the server.
Using this protocol does *not* mean you are using SSL 2.0 or 3.0 for that matter; it is merely
a handshake to determine *which* protocol to use.  [https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#appendix-E.2]

However, in Apache, if you disable SSLv3 support, this apparently removes support for the
SSLv2Hello protocol.  Apache Tomcat has explicit support for SSLv2Hello; that is, you can
enable that, but not enable SSLv3.

Is there any way to do this in Apache?

[Update]

This is my protocol config:

```
  SSLProtocol +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2 -SSLv3
```

Comment: `However, in Apache, if you disable SSLv3 support, this apparently removes support for the SSLv2Hello protocol.`

I'm running Apache 2.2 with `SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3` and the SSL 2 handshake works.

What configuration are you running exactly that you're having a problem. The only way I know to disable the SSL 2 Handshake is to enable FIPS mode.

Comment: What a pain to handle that legacy support in 2014 :( . It's time for everyone to nuke SSLv2 & SSLv3 and make universal extensions support (e.g. SNI).

Comment: @XavierLucas Instead of doing all -SSLv2, -SSLv3, I specify the TLS protocols I do support.  I don't see why that would be different, but I will test.

Comment: @ChrisS I tried both:  SSLProtocol +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2 -SSLv3 and all -SSLv3 -SSLv2.    This is running with Apache 2.4.10.  Neither configuration appears to allow the SSL 2 handshake.  And I have not touched FIPS mode; the default is that it is disabled.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently mod_ssl has changed in the last year or so (I haven't found the exact commit to the source, but found the "problem"). The source now does this:

```
If SSLProtocol only includes only one Protocol:
    Handshake = That Protocol's Handshake Only
Else
    Handshake = SSLv2 Handshake
```

There's no override for this setting. The only thing you could do is edit the source, recompile your own version. I've created a [diff](http://pastebin.com/Nvat7xTy) to force SSLv2 Handshake compatibility if you want to compile your own.

Comment: I can confirm, that Chris' patch helps -- curl (and libcurl-using programs such as git) can now talk to our server again, despite SSLv3 having been disabled -- without `sslscan` flagging any vulnerabilities. But the patch seems somewhat invasive and I'd like to ask Chris to submit it to Apache project for review ASAP. I'll file a ticket myself, if Chris does not :-)
Thank you very much, Chris!

Comment: It'd be a better idea to add a separate directive to force compatibility mode. If I have some spare time I'll write that up, but I don't think this "patch" is a good idea in the long run.

Comment: Yes, that appears to be, what Apache developers are considering. See the [thread][1] I started there...
[1]https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-dev/201410.mbox/%3C54501F91.2080104%40aldan.algebra.com%3E

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out this was a non-issue all along.  Apache will accept SSLv2 handshake with either of the configurations I posted above.  I was misled by a handshake error into thinking this was the issue; it was really just a configuration issue where the server wasn't trusting the client's CA.