# Why did git stop working after server disabled SSLv3?

Tags: ssl, git, curl, mod-ssl, github

Like most others, our repository server needs to disable SSLv3 (and v2) ASAP.

However, doing so seems to break our git-clients -- at least, on RHEL5 (connections from my FreeBSD desktop work fine). Even the most recent git (2.1.2) fails, and upgrading OpenSSL libraries to the latest from the vendor did not help.

*However*! The same git-client works just fine against github.com -- and github.com already has SSLv3 disabled too. By trial and error, I set our server's (Apache) SSL-configuration to match that of github:

```
SSLProtocol     ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLCipherSuite  "AES128-SHA AES256-SHA RC4-SHA"
```

By running `sslscan` against our server and github, I get the identical list of ciphers accepted and rejected. But git continues to fail:

```
    % git clone https://git.example.net/git/puppet-hiera
    Cloning into 'puppet-hiera'...
    * Couldn't find host git.example.net in the .netrc file, using defaults
    * About to connect() to git.example.net port 443
    *   Trying 10.89.8.27... * connected
    * Connected to git.example.net (10.89.8.27) port 443
    * successfully set certificate verify locations:
    *   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
      CApath: none
    * Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to git.example.net:443
    * Closing connection #0
    fatal: unable to access 'https://git.example.net/git/puppet-hiera/': Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to git.example.net:443
```

Now, the only perceptible difference remaining between our server's SSL and GitHub's is that `sslscan` is able to output details of GitHub's certificate, but fails to obtain those from our server.

When I connect to our git-server from my FreeBSD desktop, the same `git clone` command works. Instead of failing, after outputting `CApath: none`, I see:

```
      CApath: none
    * SSL connection using AES128-SHA
    * Server certificate:
             subject: C=US; postalCode= ............
```

and the cloning succeeds. How do I configure our server so that git works with it even from the old RHEL5-systems -- as it does against GitHub-servers?

*Update*: trying to access our server with simply `curl`, I got a similar error over SSL-compatibility. However, I was able to overcome it by invoking curl with an explicit `--tlsv1` option (also known as `-1`). So, the software on RHEL5 systems is *capable* of the necessary protocols and ciphers -- how do I make it use them by default instead of trying the old ones and failing?

Comment: It seems pretty likely that git is compiled against a version of the SSL libraries that doesn't include support for newer protocols.

Comment: That what I thought until I tested the *same* git against github -- which offers the exact same protocol-collection -- and found, that that worked...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, here is the deal. Disabling SSLv3 in today's Apache means, the server would not even tell the client, that it wants to use TLS. If the client does not *begin* the conversation with TLS, the client will fail -- even if *could* talk TLS. Many thanks to user [Chris S.](https://serverfault.com/users/33417/chris-s), who analyzed the problem and even offered a [patch](http://pastebin.com/Nvat7xTy) for Apache's `mod_ssl` in answering a [related question](https://serverfault.com/questions/637880/disabling-sslv3-but-still-supporting-sslv2hello-in-apache/).

Having looked at Chris' patch, Apache developers have come up with a more comprehensive one, which might even become part of the next Apache-release. It introduces a new option for Apache's `SSLProtocols` directive: `ANY`. When Apache encounters the `ANY`, it will advise the connecting client (via SSLv2Hello), that it must switch to TLS:

```
SSLProtocol ANY -SSLv2 -SSLv3
```

I'm pasting the patch here for those, who can't afford to wait for Apache 2.4.11.

```
Index: modules/ssl/ssl_private.h
===================================================================
--- modules/ssl/ssl_private.h    (revision 1635012)
+++ modules/ssl/ssl_private.h    (working copy)
@@ -295,8 +295,10 @@ typedef int ssl_opt_t;
 #define SSL_PROTOCOL_TLSV1_2 (1<<4)
 #define SSL_PROTOCOL_ALL   (SSL_PROTOCOL_SSLV3|SSL_PROTOCOL_TLSV1| \
                 SSL_PROTOCOL_TLSV1_1|SSL_PROTOCOL_TLSV1_2)
+#define SSL_PROTOCOL_ANY   (1<<5)
 #else
 #define SSL_PROTOCOL_ALL   (SSL_PROTOCOL_SSLV3|SSL_PROTOCOL_TLSV1)
+#define SSL_PROTOCOL_ANY   (1<<3)
 #endif
 typedef int ssl_proto_t;

Index: modules/ssl/ssl_engine_init.c
===================================================================
--- modules/ssl/ssl_engine_init.c    (revision 1635012)
+++ modules/ssl/ssl_engine_init.c    (working copy)
@@ -490,6 +490,7 @@ static apr_status_t ssl_init_ctx_protocol(server_r
     }

     cp = apr_pstrcat(p,
+                     (protocol & SSL_PROTOCOL_ANY ? "SSLv23, " : ""),
              (protocol & SSL_PROTOCOL_SSLV3 ? "SSLv3, " : ""),
              (protocol & SSL_PROTOCOL_TLSV1 ? "TLSv1, " : ""),
 #ifdef HAVE_TLSV1_X
Index: modules/ssl/ssl_engine_config.c
===================================================================
--- modules/ssl/ssl_engine_config.c    (revision 1635012)
+++ modules/ssl/ssl_engine_config.c    (working copy)
@@ -1311,6 +1311,9 @@ static const char *ssl_cmd_protocol_parse(cmd_parm
     else if (strcEQ(w, "all")) {
         thisopt = SSL_PROTOCOL_ALL;
     }
+        else if (strcEQ(w, "any")) {
+            thisopt = SSL_PROTOCOL_ANY|SSL_PROTOCOL_ALL;
+        }
     else {
         return apr_pstrcat(parms->temp_pool,
                parms->cmd->name,
Index: modules/ssl/ssl_engine_io.c
===================================================================
--- modules/ssl/ssl_engine_io.c    (revision 1635012)
+++ modules/ssl/ssl_engine_io.c    (working copy)
@@ -1137,6 +1137,7 @@ static apr_status_t ssl_io_filter_handshake(ssl_fi
      * IPv4 and IPv6 addresses are not permitted".)
      */
     if (hostname_note &&
+            !(sc->proxy->protocol & SSL_PROTOCOL_ANY) &&
         sc->proxy->protocol != SSL_PROTOCOL_SSLV3 &&
         apr_ipsubnet_create(&ip, hostname_note, NULL,
                 c->pool) != APR_SUCCESS) {
```

Comment: Could you link the discussion/patch for the fix in Apache for some more information on this topic?

Comment: The discussion just resumed after a couple of days of quiet -- it may be, the above patch will not be final after all. But it works :) Here is a link to one of online archives of HTTPD dev-mailing lists: http://www.mail-archive.com/dev%40httpd.apache.org/msg60833.html

Answer (score 0):

I like the explanation you've provided for how to make server-side adjustments to get git clients working. My issue was trying to connect to jazzhub where I do not have the ability to change the server. I came up with this solution today (and late last night):

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/answers/164635/view.html

If you have some feedback on it, I'd love to hear it.

-Michael

Comment: What is the solution? Remember that answers here must not consist _solely_ of links to external sites.